# Valid use of differentiable almost everywhere functions, like hinge loss, in gradient optimization/learners, like SciKit-Learn's SGDClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, loss-functions, gradient

So, my abstract question is: is it valid (in the sense that stable convergence is *roughly* expected) to use functions that are differentiable *almost* everywhere *in the practical application of* optimization/learner techniques that take gradients of these functions.

Or, more specifically: should I expect utilization of SciKit-Learn's Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier (SGDClassifier) to produce reliable, valid results using its default loss function of hinge loss. Of course, this question could also apply to use of differentiable almost everywhere function within a neural network with backward-propagation.

A survey of facts:

- (Stochastic) gradient descent *theoretically* requires that functions it optimizes are differentiable, convex, and Lipschitz
- The hinge loss function is not differentiable everywhere (not at y=1), given its definition in terms of   as (()) where () = max(0,1− ) and ()= ⋅
- So, *theoretically*, the hinge loss function cannot be used with (stochastic) gradient descent, but sub-gradient methods should work
- However, a gradient of the hinge loss function can be defined where the value at 1 can be forced to exist to be value to the right (or to the left)
- Additionally, it has been suggested that gradient descent methods are decently robust to non-convexity
- Lastly, it appears to me that the SGDClassifier within SciKit-Learn uses the hinge loss function by default without any notes about an underlying use of sub-gradient methods

So, perhaps, I should take the performance of the default configured SGDClassifier as evidence that gradient descent methods (and more generally optimization methods utilizing gradients) are robust to functions that are differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: I understand that the convergence guarantee of (S)GD is further dependent on the function to be Lipschitz. It is tempting to wonder if differentiable almost everywhere functions that are also Lipschitz may have better chance to "work", however, I do understand that there are pathological cases like abs(x) that will not converge with (S)GD using a fixed step size but abs(x) is a Lipschitz differentiable almost everywhere function. However, I am looking for practical reliability not proofs.

Comment: (Some of the above was informed by this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885101/why-do-we-need-sub-gradient-methods-for-non-differentiable-functions.)

Comment: many (not all) results for gradient-based optimization can be generalized to [subgradient-based methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method) (subgradients are generalizations of gradients for convex functions which coincide with gradients in the differentiable case). That might lead you toward finding a satisfying answer to your answer